# How to get and use class/entity type by reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection, repository

I have these entities that are being called at runtime and I need to be able to return an `IQueryable<EntityObject>` based on the entity type being called that particular time by string. Let's say the entity is types of food and the class name is `Food`, so...

```
return Repository.Read<Food>();    //this is what I am trying to accomplish
```

However, I don't know that it is `Food` until runtime and is such only given as a string, so I use reflection:

```
Type t = Type.GetType(lookupEntityName);    //where lookupEntityName = "Food"
```

How can I use this `Type t` to replace 'Food' in the original line of code from above:

```
return Repository.Read<HERE>();    // use 't' to repalce "HERE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your method only contains a return statement (because you have only posted that), you could do something like this (warning: this wasn't tested):

```
public static IQueryable<T> Read<T>()
{
    return Repository.Read<T>();
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
IQueryable<Food> food = Read<Food>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create  your generic method at runtime.

```
var openMethod = typeof(Repository).GetMethod(nameof(Repository.Read), ...);
var closedMethod = openMethod.MakeGenericMethod(t);
return closedMethod.Invoke(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call a generic method, you must get the MethodInfo of that function and create a generic MethodInfo for the appropiate type.

This is a helper function to do this:

```
public MethodInfo GetGenericMethod(string MethodName, Type SourceType, Type TargetType)
{
    var mInfo = SourceType.GetMethod(MethodName);
    return mInfo.MakeGenericMethod(TargetType);
}
```

And now you can do this:

```
Type t = Type.GetType(lookupEntityName);
Type tSrc = typeof(Repository);

var result = GetGenericMethod("Read", tSrc, t).Invoke(Repository);
```

If Read is an static method then pass null to the invoke.